# MIDI-Channel-Track-Correlation

Tags: java, midi

I've been working form some time with JAVA MIDI and I've stumbled upon a problem.
I've linked using the Receiver,Transmitter method a MIDI device an 
  MPD with a sequencer ,then linked the sequencer to the Java synthesizer.

I've managed to record on separate tracks the data from the device so as an example:

track[0] has some Midi Events

track[1] has some Midi Events  etc.

The problems is because all tracks when recorded use the same channel if a track changes the sound PROGRAM_CHANGE all the tracks change to that sound when the sequencer starts playing.The MIDI device I guess just uses 1 channel: channel 1 to transmit the data to the sequencer and when the sequencer writes the data to tracks all have the same channel so I can't play the tracks with different instruments.
    "Record_Enable" only work on channel 1(only there I get data from the device to the sequencer).
I think there are 2 solutions but I don't know how to implement them.

1.Either change channels for each track.

So track[0] has all MIDI events on channel 0.

track[1] has all MIDI events on channel 1. etc

2.Make the device somehow send data to sequencer on different channels.

Comment: In MIDI, a channel effectively is a track.  The synth won't allow you to assign two instruments to a single channel... how would it know what messages to send to what instrument?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do modify the data so I can change the channel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the channel of an event's message, use [setMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ShortMessage.html#setMessage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with a different `channel` parameter.
Do this for all events in the track.

Comment: Maybe but using the set-message method just makes me recreate the message from scratch.What do I do when i don't know what was the original message.(I need to get the default data from the MIDI event and just modify the channel but I don't know how to do this).

Comment: You already *have* the message object; just ask it what the other parameters are.